# Regex Numbers with 0 or 1 - follow by numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string, numbers, match

I'm trying to match this string, but I'm not getting to work. The string can only have either numbers or numbers with 1 dash follow by another set of numbers.

My Regex Formula:

```
^([0-9]*|[0-9]*\-{1}[0-9]*)$
```

EX:

This Pass

```
123
```

This pass

```
123-123
```

This should fail, but it's passing

```
123-
```

Comment: `*` in a regexes means zero or more. `123-` has zero or more digits following the dash.

Comment: is `-123` valid? is `123--123` valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the simplest and most efficient way of doing it:

`^\d+(?:-\d+)?$`

`^[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$`*

- `\d` is a character set available in most regex flavors that represents `[0-9]`. It's a more concise way of matching numerals, but if you prefer `[0-9]` you can just use that instead.
- Note that your original pattern and the patterns offered by others as answers here included the quantifier `{1}` after the hyphen. This should be avoided, as it's always redundant. A single character without a quantifier is equivalent to the same character followed by `{1}`.

*Edit: Wiktor brought up something I wasn't aware of. In certain regex flavors, `\d` includes all unicode digits rather than just the numerals 0 through 9. If this is an issue, you can just use the pattern `^[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Watch out for [strings like `๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑-௫௬௭௮`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a-%5cd%2b%29%3f%24&i=%e0%b9%94%e0%b9%95%e0%b9%96%e0%b9%97%e0%b9%98%e0%b9%99%e0%bb%90%e0%bb%91-%e0%af%ab%e0%af%ac%e0%af%ad%e0%af%ae).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Didn't know about that! Added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what the different parts of your regular expression are doing. The `*` symbolizes zero or any number of some symbol, in your case a number.

If you want at least one number after the dash use `+` instead of the star.

```
^([0-9]*|[0-9]*\-{1}[0-9]+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close!

The `*` quantifier matches 0 or more digits.

What you're looking for is the `+` quantifier which matches 1 or more digits.

Modifying your example:

```
^([0-9]*|[0-9]+\-{1}[0-9]+)$
```

Will match either nothing, a single number, or a number-number

Answer (score 0):

`^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*$`

`^[0-9]+` starts with one or more numbers

`(-[0-9]+)*`    zero or one occurance of a dash followed by a number with length of 1 or more

Answer (score 0):

For the fun here are some regex-free answers. I find them easier to read.

If `-123` and `123--123` are not allowed:

```
s.Split('-').All(x => x != string.Empty && x.All(char.IsDigit));
```

Foreach element between `-`, we check that this element is not empty and made of number only.

If `-123` and `123--123` are allowed:

```
!s.EndsWith("-") && s.All(c => c == '-' || char.IsDigit(c));
```

Check that a string `s` does not end with `-` and that `s` is made of `-` and numbers only.

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uB3O91)

Note that `char.IsDigit` will allow `๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑-௫௬௭௮`. If you don't want to match this replace `char.IsDigit()` with `IsDigit()`:

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c) => c >= '0' && c <= '9';
```